# how to remove the control button in an uploaded video in qualtrics

Tags: html, qualtrics

I was wondering whether I can remove the control button & progress bar from the uploaded video on Qualtrics. Any suggestions? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I would suggest you add more details to your question. For example, where are you displaying the video? What is your end goal? Are you embedding the video? etc

Comment: This is only configurable by certain video players. it cannot be done in Qualtrics' built in player. the only one I know of that it can be done it is Brightcove.

Comment: I was just wondering if Qualtrics can allow me to do that with builtin player, thanks for the information!